# Порт клиента при UDP запросе через сокет

Tags: delphi, сокет, udp, port

Создаю UDP запрос на NTP сервер. Он приходит и обрабатывается, но порт клиента каждый раз разный.

Пример на Delphi

```
Sock:=Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);      
FillChar(Addr.sin_zero, SizeOf(Addr.sin_zero), 0);  
Addr.sin_family:=AF_INET;                       
Addr.sin_addr.S_addr:=inet_addr('192.168.8.3');  
Addr.sin_port:=htons(123);
AddrLen:=SizeOf(Addr);
SendTo(Sock, PChar(@Mes)^, 48, 0, Addr,SizeOf(Addr));  
CloseSocket(Sock);
```

В логе сервера

```
192.168.8.1 [1195]  
192.168.8.1 [1208]  
192.168.8.1 [1209]
```

Вопрос - как задать фиксированный порт клиента.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках вопроса (я вижу, что это что-то паскалеподобное, но лучше указать точно, чтобы не нужно было угадывать).

Comment: 0) А зачем? 1) Если вы постоянно пересоздаёте сокет, то логично, что каждый раз порт будет новый. Вы уверены, что вам нужно его пересоздавать? 2) Можно вручную задать порт через bind, однако если вы постоянно пересоздаёте сокет, то имейте в виду, что желаемый вами порт может случайно оказаться занят каким-нибудь другим сокетом

Comment: Пишу свой NTP сервер (он же и клиент) на сокетах. С INDY компонентом TIdUDPServer всё отлично работает, могу задать порт клиента 123. Сервер обрабатывает и отправляет по этому же адресу, соответственно запросы с адресом отличным от 123 уйдут в никуда...

Comment: Вам должно быть без разницы какой порт использует клиент, т к это не сервер, и он может использовать любой порт, обратная связь получается из пакета который вы отправляете, и должны получить этим же клиентом ответ, а вы его закрываете, не получив ответ.

Comment: Я хочу сделать и клиент, и сервер в одном флаконе. В отдельном потоке слушаю 123 порт (и отвечаю на запросы) - это серверная часть. Так же есть кнопочка сформировать запрос на другой сервер, на другой машине, где будет этот самый клиент/сервер.Запрос уходит и ответ должен вернуться на 123 порт, где его обработает сервер. Как показывает компонент TIdUDPServer это возможно - задать конкретный порт клиентского запрса.

Comment: «ответ должен вернуться на 123 порт» — почему? Здравый смысл подсказывает мне, что ответ на запрос клиента должен приходить клиенту, а не серверу

Comment: Так оно и есть. Давайте не будем вдаваться в тонкости. У меня вопрос - "как задать фиксированный порт клиента"